# how to concat on element to other in same list based on condition

Tags: python, list

I have a list of items : eg:

```
a = ['when', '#i am here','#go and get it', '#life is hell', 'who', '#i am here','#go and get it',]
```

I want to merge the list items based on condition i.e merge all the items till the item has # in first place and replace it with when or who. The output I want is :

```
['when', 'when i am here','when go and get it', 'when life is hell', 'who', 'who i am here','who go and get it',]
```

Comment: Seems pretty straightforward. Can you show what you've tried and describe how it's failing?

Comment: show what have you tried

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate over `a`, save the word if it does not start with`'#'`, or replace `'#'` with the saved word if it does:

```
for i, s in enumerate(a):
    if s.startswith('#'):
        a[i] = p + s[1:]
    else:
        p = s + ' '
```

`a` becomes:

```
['when', 'when i am here', 'when go and get it', 'when life is hell', 'who', 'who i am here', 'who go and get it']
```

Answer (score 0):

Just going off the info you provided, you could do this.

```
    a = ['when', '#i am here','#go and get it', '#life is hell', 'who', '#i am here','#go and get it']
    whoWhen = ""                                                 #are we adding 'who or when'
    output = []                                                  #new list
    for i in a:                                                  #loop through
        if " " not in i:                                         #if there's only 1 word
            whoWhen = i + " "                                    #specify we will use that word
            output.append(i.upper())                             #put it in the list
        else:                           
            output.append(i.replace("#", whoWhen))               #replace hashtag with word
    print(output)
```

Prints:

```
['WHEN', 'when i am here', 'when go and get it', 'when life is hell', 'WHO', 'who i am here', 'who go and get it']

Process returned 0 (0x0)        execution time : 0.062 s
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Comment: Why `upper()`? OP didnt mention anywhere

Comment: @mad_ Just for style, doesn't affect the functionality. I just thought it was hard to read where the keywords were in lowercase.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
def carry_concat(string_list):
    replacement = ""  # current replacement string ("when" or "who" or whatever)
    replaced_list = []  # the new list
    for value in string_list:
        if value[0] == "#":
            # add string with replacement
            replaced_list.append(replacement + " " + value[1:])
        else:
            # set this string as the future replacement value
            replacement = value
            # add string without replacement
            replaced_list.append(value)
    return replaced_list

a = ['when', '#i am here','#go and get it', '#life is hell', 'who', '#i am here','#go and get it',]

print(a)
print(carry_concat(a))
```

This prints:

```
['when', '#i am here', '#go and get it', '#life is hell', 'who', '#i am here', '#go and get it']
['when', 'when i am here', 'when go and get it', 'when life is hell', 'who', 'who i am here', 'who go and get it']
```